# Invalid Zend_Validate_Float

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I am using the Float validation, to validate the data on my Zend_Form field.

But the behavior of validation is something that is of concern.

It validates correctly, if the form is posted through Firefox or Chrome, but it says invalid when used through IE.

With IE, it validates any value greater 10, i.e. greater than 10.00, but says invalid if the value is lower than 10.00

There has been no locale defined for the form, so i guess it would take default as `en`.

I understand the validation are something that works on server-side and the client interface should not make an impact, but it still seems to be so.

**Form Class :**

```
class Application_Form_Custom extends Zend_Form {
    public function init() {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setName('form_custom');
        $this->setElementFilters(array('StringTrim','StripTags'));

        $notEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
        $notEmpty->setMessage('Value is required', 'isEmpty');

        $valid_float = new Zend_Validate_Float();
        $valid_float -> setMessages(array(
            'floatInvalid' => 'Invalid',
            'notFloat'     => 'Invalid'
        ));
        $deposit = new Zend_Form_Element_Text(array(
            'name' => 'txtDeposit',
            'style' => 'width:99%;',
            'autocomplete' => 'off'
        ));
        $deposit -> setLabel('Deposit : ');
        $deposit -> setValue('0.00');
        $deposit -> setRequired(true);
        $deposit -> addValidators(array(array(
            $notEmpty,
            true
        ), array(
            $valid_float,
            true
        )));

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('btnSubmit');
        $submit -> setLabel('Submit');
        $reset = new Zend_Form_Element_Reset('btnReset');
        $reset -> setLabel('Reset');

        $this->addElements(array(
            $deposit,
            $submit,
            $reset
        ));
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class FormsController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function customFormAction() {
        $form= new Application_Form_Custom();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
            ///...blah...blah...about my process
        }
        $this->view->form =$form;
    }
}
```

**View :**

```
<form id="<?php echo $this->form->getName(); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->form->getName(); ?>" action="" method="<?php echo $this->form->getMethod(); ?>">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">Deposit</td>
          <td><?php echo $this->form->txtDeposit->renderViewHelper(); 
          if(count($this->form->txtDeposit->getMessages()) > 0) {
              ?><br />
            <div style="color:#F00;">
              <?php
              $i=0;
              foreach($this->form->txtDeposit->getMessages() as $msg) {
                  echo $msg;
                  $i++;
                  if(count($this->form->txtDeposit->getMessages())>$i) {
                    echo '<br />';
                  }
              }
              ?>
            </div>
            <?php

          }
          ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left" valign="top">
          <td colspan="2" align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $this->form->btnSubmit->renderViewHelper(); ?> <?php echo $this->form->btnReset->renderViewHelper(); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: First which IE is causing problems? Are you using any javascript shiv for html5 compatibility? Have you cleared cache and history and tried again?

Comment: Could you also copy/paste your code here.

Comment: @RockyFord there are no javascript used for form validation or any other animation, the layout is a XHTML Strict Document

Comment: @Liyali the codes have been added

Comment: What does `echo new Zend_Locale();` shows in the IE?

Comment: RockyFord already asked but which version of IE are you using?

Comment: have you tried it after setting the Zend_locale, this will help you to confirm if the issue is due to the locale setting

Comment: @Liyali, RockyFord: I am using IE9 on Win7, the results is also invlaid with other versions too.